# How do I check ReSharper code inspections of Unity Project via a command line?

Tags: unity-game-engine, teamcity, resharper, rider

**Given:**

- Unity project
- ReSharper is used to check inspections
  (IDE Rider)

**I want to:**

- Run code inspections on a CI / CD system
  (TeamCity)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run inspections from the command line, you need:

1. Download [ReSharper command line tools](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/download/#section=commandline)
2. Download [Unity plugin for ReSharper](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/11629-unity-support)
3. Put the plugin in the root of the ReSharper folder
4. Run the tool: `InspectCode.exe YourSolution.sln -o=<PathToOutputFile>` [More options](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/InspectCode.html)
5. Get a beautiful XML report

TeamCity has a special runner type to run such checks: [Inspections (ReSharper)﻿](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/inspections-resharper.html)

In the `R# CLT Plugins` field, you will need to specify the Unity plugin, for example: `Download JetBrains.Unity/2021.2.0.129`

If the `.sln` file is not generated at the previous steps of building your project, you can generate it with running Unity with the parameter `-executeMethod UnityEditor.SyncVS.SyncSolution`